# SQLite working ok on Android 2.2 on device and on Android 4.1 in emulator, but not on Android 4.1 on device

Tags: android, sqlite

I have some problems with SQLite.
My application working perfectly on Android 2.2 (real device & emulator), and on Android 4.1 in emulator.

On device with Android 4 I have troubles.
SQLite does not want to execute simple "CREATE TABLE" statement.
Screenshot is attached.

What can be wrong?

[image: SQLite]

Full-size image can be found here: http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/7815/lsut.jpg

Comment: Can you post your code, especially the SQL create statement you're using?

Comment: Compile your own sqlite, don't use a precompiled library.

Comment: CREATE TABLE categories (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT);

Comment: Please post the code you used to generate the SQLite Table in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
near " CREATE": syntax error
```

There should be no space character before the `CREATE`.
Apparently, you have a non-breaking space (or some other control character) instead of a normal space character. Remove it.